# Multi tenant table design - Shard model - What should be the table identifier?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, multi-tenant, database-performance, saas

I'm creating a SaaS application and I'm using the Multi DB - Multi-Tenant database model, meaning multiple tenants can share the same database. Tenants will be placed in databases depending on their usage or activities. Now I'm just wondering about how I should store the data in databases for the best performance. What should be the primary keys and/or indexes of the tables?
I have the tenant Id on every single table in the databases.

Tenant Table:

```
tenant_id [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
name [VARCHAR] NOT NULL,
...
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (tenant_id)
```

User Table:

```
user_id [INT]nIDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
name [VARCHAR] NOT NULL,
...
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (user_id)
FOREIGN KEY (tenant_id)
```

Order Table:

```
order_id [INT]IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
date [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
...
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (order_id)
FOREIGN KEY (tenant_id)
```

Not sure if this is a good design. What should be the primary key and/or indexes of the tables?
Based on the fact that every single query in the app should have the tenant_id.

option 1:
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (order_id) and NON CLUSTERED INDEX on (tenant_id)

option 2:
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (order_id) and NON CLUSTERED INDEX on (tenant_id, order_id)

option 3:
PRIMARY KEY NON CLUSTERED (order_id) and CLUSTERED INDEX on (tenant_id, order_id)

option 4:
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (tenant_id, order_id)

I would greatly appreciate your suggestions or advice. Thanks

Comment: I will opt to use a GUID for identifiers so that you can accommodate a very large set of data and not run out of ids

Comment: Yes, I may consider using a GUID for identifiers. But I'm more concerned about the way of storing the data in the tables for the best performance of the queries.